# Someone who owns the the rights to a song

Tags: synonyms

To give an example. A song may have sampled another older song. In order to get clearance to use this sampled song, the former party must contact the sampled song's *owner*. I've seen instances where you have a music label that grants the rights to use a sample and another party that actually grants the license which makes this a little more confusing:

[image]

Other than using the term *owner* what would be another, more specific name? The only one that comes to mind would be *rights holder* but after searching on the web I'm not 100% sure if that's correct.

Comment: You mean like a licensor? I think in my those are called Labels? Not sure.

Comment: Well that's where it gets tricky. I've seen instances where you have a music label that grants the rights to use a sample and another party that actually grants the license. I'll attach a screenshot of this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person or company involved are referred to as the ***[copyright owners](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright):***

> - ***Copyright is a legal right created by the law of a country that grants the creator of an original work exclusive rights for its use and distribution***. This is usually only for a limited time. The exclusive rights are not absolute but limited by limitations and exceptions to copyright law, including fair use. A major limitation on copyright is that copyright protects only the original expression of ideas, and not the underlying ideas themselves.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: +1, but I note that *copyright holder* is becoming increasingly common: [ngram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copyright+owner%2C+copyright+holder&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccopyright%20owner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopyright%20holder%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What then would be the differentiating factor between a copyright owner and licensor?

Comment: I may own the copyright to something I've written, but a licensor handles all the licensing (eg collecting royalties and passing them to me). In the UK, this role is handled by organisations like the Performing Right Society (now [PRS for Music](https://www.prsformusic.com/)) and [CCLI](http://uk.ccli.com/), among others.